# how to fix "difference from first mismatch" from line 1

Tags: python-3.x

I am new in coding. I am solving the hackerearth problem "Ali and helping innocent people " but after running that code I get a mismatch error 
and two test case failed after run my code. my code compile successfully but not run successfully. please suggest me what is error in my code.

[This is the assignment](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/input-output/basics-of-input-output/practice-problems/algorithm/cartag-948c2b02/)

> Arpasland has surrounded by attackers. A truck enters the city. The
>   driver claims the load is food and medicine from Iranians. Ali is one
>   of the soldiers in Arpasland. He doubts about the truck, maybe it's
>   from the siege. He knows that a tag is valid if the sum of every two
>   consecutive digits of it is even and its letter is not a vowel.
>   Determine if the tag of the truck is valid or not.
>
> We consider the letters "A","E","I","O","U","Y" to be vowels for this
>   problem.
>
> **Input Format**
>
> The first line contains a string of length 9. The format is
>   "DDXDDD-DD", where D stands for a digit (non zero) and X is an
>   uppercase english letter.
>
> **Output Format**
>
> Print "valid" (without quotes) if the tag is valid, print "invalid"
>   otherwise (without quotes)

```
s=input()
l=len(s)
for i in range(l):
     for j in range(i+1,l):
          if((i!="A" and i!="E" and i!="I" and i!="O" and i!="U" and i!="Y")):
               if((i==3 and (i+j)%2==0) and (i==5  and ((i+2)%2)==0) ):
                       print("Valid")
else:
    print("invalid")
```

Comment: Else block is not indented properly

Comment: You should include the question clearly,and the error/output you get for this code vs expected output

Answer (score 0):

Because your code is evaluating sum of position s[1] + s[3] and s[5]+s[7] to be
an even digit and that's why it is  returning some test cases as incorrect.Look after the test cases and question carefully.